# What's wrong with my date_query?

Tags: archives, get-posts, date

It's WordPress 3.9 "Smith". I'm trying to implement a [new Archive page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/124102/22728) as per [the suggestion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124103/22728) of @Milo.

```
$categories = get_categories( $cat_args ); //it's NOT important for the Q, as it's fetching perfectly

foreach( $categories as $category ) {

                        $args = array(
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'category__in' => array( $category->term_id ),
                            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'date_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                    'after'    => array(
                                                        'year'  => 2014,
                                                        'month' => 01,
                                                        'day'   => 25,
                                                    ),
                                                    'before'    => array(
                                                        'year'  => 2014,
                                                        'month' => 01,
                                                        'day'   => 25,
                                                    ),
                                                    'inclusive' => true,
                                                ),
                                            )
                        );

                        $posts = get_posts( $args );
                        var_dump($posts);
}
```

I'll make the hard-coded dates into dynamic with Milo's suggestion, but with this hard coding, the `var_dump($posts)` is showing **empty** arrays.

I'm following [Viper007Bond.com's tutorial](http://www.viper007bond.com/2013/08/27/date-queries-in-wordpress-3-point-7/) on WP `date_query` and I have posts on Jan25 and Jan22. I tried changing the `day` value from 22,24,25 etc, but the results are empty arrays.

And of course the code I pasted here is from `archive.php` where my URL is in:

```
http://localhost/project_name/date/2014/01/25/
```

Comment: Thanks @G.M. for the insight. I'm just trying to query the posts within a day/month/year.

Comment: So you are returning posts that are in a specific `Term`. I realise you are looping through all `Terms` from the `Category` taxonomy, but are you 100% sure that your posts are actually in any of those `Terms`?

Comment: @G.M. Yes, that's the answer. Solved my problem. Can you please add both the comment as an **Answer** so that I can give you the actual credit and we can make the post helpful for the future query? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'date_query'` argument takes an additional option that is 'relation' that can be `AND` or `OR`.

If we consider the relation `OR` your code, that use exactly same date for 'before' and 'after' with 'inclusive' set to true, should return all your posts: posts before a date + posts after that date + posts in that date.

If we consider the relation AND, it can be summarized in `post_date >= date && post_date <= date` and that it's true for date itself, but probably there's something on date query class (I've not digged in the core) that prevents such a query, that to be honest, make no sense to me.

The reason is simple: if you want to query a specific date you don't need to use after/before at all, just create an array with the year, month and day you want to display

```
$args = array(
  'date_query' => array(
    array(
      'year'  => 2012,
      'month' => 12,
      'day'   => 12,
    ),
  ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The code above is taken from second example for date query parameters in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters).